# Backbone - toggleClass on hover

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, addclass, toggleclass

I am new to Backbone and understand the idea, but am having trouble properly writing a simple toggleClass function. My site is a grid of squares that when a square has the class "hover" some css causes the appearance to change (obviously). My problem is the toggleClass is not working. My code is as follows:

```
var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('#main'),
indexTemplate: $("#indexSquare").template(),

events: {
"mouseover .square"  : "mouseovercard"
},

render: function() {
    removeFallbacks();
    var sg = this;

    this.el.fadeOut('fast', function() {
    sg.el.empty();
    $.tmpl(sg.indexTemplate, sg.model.toArray()).appendTo(sg.el);
    sg.el.fadeIn('fast');
    });
    return this;
},

mouseovercard: function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('hover')
    console.log("hey you're hovering!")

}

});
```

What exactly is wrong here? Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in your code refers to the `View` object, use `currentTarget` property of the `event` object.

```
mouseovercard: function(event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('hover');
    console.log("hey you're hovering!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$el](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) property of backbone View:

```
this.$el.toggleClass('hover');
```